# Browser hiding images when site online, works as intended offline

Tags: html, css, web

Code works fine when offline, however when I upload it to the site the images for the social media buttons don't show, on further inspection the code being overridden by the browser

it looks like:

`<img src="images/facebook.png" class="socialbuttons" alt="find on facebook" width="0" height="0" style="display: none !important; visibility: hidden !important; opacity: 0 !important; background-position: 0px 0px;">`

instead of:

```
<img src="images/facebook.png" class="socialbuttons" alt="find on facebook">
```

for the images. I've tried using different images, changing the class to something else and viewing on other browsers.
I tried to override it using `!important` but that doesn't work either.

The address of the site is 
http://markncarolproperties.co.uk/

stack overflow won't let me post images, imgur links instead
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ADAv.jpg

Comment: I think this is because you have a sort of ad-blocking / social network button blocking add-on activated. For me the website just works fine...

Comment: You don't need to include the `<HTML><CSS>` in your title, nor the "screenshots enclosed". Just state what the question or issue is. And yes, the facebook icon seems fine to me too in Chrome.

Comment: Expanding the comment above: it might be useful (as you are a new user) for you to read this, Craig: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks for the comments, it was indeed my ad blocker, it's been a long day.
Will take that onboard in future, thanks for taking the time to reply.

Comment: @TomášZato I totally agree, but I think it is also useful to provide the link, because it contains much more information, which might result in a general improvement of his future questions.

Comment: @Rsauxil See the difference between *also* and *instead*. I'm not saying you did anything wrong.

Comment: @TomášZato, Woops, my bad, read over that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solution is:

- customize your `adBlock`
- add your website to the "Show ads on a webpage or domain" list

Answer (score 0):

I use Chrome with adblock and the images come up just fine. If it is still an issue, try changing the names to something simpler like FB.png ?

Without being able to replicate the issue or see it as it is working, I cannot even use Chrome's Inspect Element tool.